# Bot wont properly print member_count

Tags: discord.py

So I'm new to Python and I decided to take the plunge and make a Discord bot for personal use in my server. I like the idea of having full control over what features my bot will have so I'm slowly building the bot. Currently I want my bot to show the current number of members in the server when called with a command

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@botbot.command()
async def server(ctx):
    guild = discord.Guild.member_count
    await ctx.send(guild)
```

I know I'm most likely way off with my code here.

While the bot is sending a message into the chat, its formatted as:

`<property object at 0x046036C0>`

While I would like to have it say something like "This server has {some number} members."

Any advice is really appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

Edit: botbot is the name for my bot, just so thats clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.Guild` is the class.  You want to get the guild the command is in from the invocation context:

```
@botbot.command()
async def server(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"This server has {ctx.guild.member_count} members.")
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved the issue and does exactly what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The method member_count is not really what you want in this occasion, the guild object has a list called members, so it's as easy as getting the length of that list like so:

```
@botbot.command()
async def server(ctx):
guild = len(discord.guild.members)
await ctx.send(guild)
```

EDIT: And indeed you have a typo with using "Guild" instead of "guild"

Comment: Thank you for the response! Im afraid your solution raises an error, "discord.guild has no module members". However Patricks solution did resolve the issue.